# iText not showing image if adding template

Tags: itext

If adding template to contentByte then the image that is added to document is not shown.

```java
writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
cb = writer.getDirectContent();
document.newPage();

//*******************************************************
// *** adding following line causes the image not to be shown ***
cb.addTemplate(form, 0, 0);
//*******************************************************

cb.beginText();
cb.setRGBColorFill(0,0,0);
cb.setFontAndSize(bf, fontSize);

//*******************************************************
// *** the image is shown only if addTemplate is not called above.***
document.add(image);
//*******************************************************

cb.showTextAligned(...);
cb.endText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by calling writer.getDirectContentUnder(); instead of writer.getDirectContent();